# Maximal inequality for Markov process

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, markov-chains

For a Markov process $\{X_n\}$ is there any inequality available for 
$$ E[\sup_{0 \leq n \leq k} X_{n}]$$
in terms of moments of $E[X_n], 0 \leq n \leq k$

Comment: certainly not - there are zero mean MC's. You need to assume more, either higher moments or something about the state space.

Comment: @oferzeitouni: Thanks. That is ok. I am not asking for general case. Can you please give me some references ?

Comment: You could benefit by looking at the [Doob's martingale inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_inequality). You can look at its proof to see if you can do something similar for Markov processes, though I am not sure if it will be fruitful.

Comment: @SamratMukhopadhyay: Unlike submarttingale, Markov chain sampled at increasing stopping times may not be a Markov Chain. And the proof you told depends on this heavily.